# merge n arrays in one multidimensional in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to merge n arrays in one multidimensional.

Example:

```
a = [ a1, a2 ]
b = [ b1, b2 ]
```

the result should be a multidimensional array like so:

```
[ a1, b1 ]
[ a1, b2 ]
[ a2, b1 ]
[ a2, b2 ]
```

but this should work for a n number of arrays ( the result should be the same ), I'm sure that this should be done in a recursive way.

Comment: Please show some effort on your own part, rather than just asking the community to do your work for you.

Comment: So you want any combination of elements in the input arrays to appear in the output array?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** and include valid code to reproduce it. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

First calculate the longest array.

Then loop over the arrays, and loop over the items.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/xG62f/)

```
var a = [ 'a1', 'a2' ],
    b = [ 'b1', 'b2' ],
    c = [ 'c1', 'c2', 'c3' ];



var to2DArray = function(){
    var maxLength = 0,
        arrays = arguments;
        resultArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i< arrays.length; i++){
        if(arrays[i].length > maxLength) maxLength = arrays[i].length;
    }
    for(var j = 0; j < maxLength; j++){
        var subArray = [];
        for(var i = 0; i< arrays.length; i++){
            if(arrays[i][j] !== undefined) subArray.push(arrays[i][j]);
        }
        resultArray.push(subArray);
    }
    return resultArray;
}

console.log(to2DArray(a, b, c)); //resulting in: [["a1","b1","c1"],["a2","b2","c2"],["c3"]]
```